# Children's component not being removed if there is only one child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, children

I have imported some .obj's, all of them have a different amount of children, some with 1 some with more. In my game I am able to use the mouse to select one of these .obj's, and it puts an outline around the one I have selected.

My deselection functionality doesn't seem to work correctly though. When trying to delete the script for the outline from one of these objects it wont do it if the object only has one child. 2 children seems to work fine every-time, but 1 child doesn't. It is for sure entering the child deletion loop, I debugged that recently, but it only enters it once as opposed to objects with 2 children entering the loop thrice.

Any idea what could be the issue here?

```
        if(selected != null){
            Transform[] ts = selected.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
            foreach (Transform child in ts){
                Destroy(child.gameObject.GetComponent<cakeslice.Outline>());
            }
            Destroy(selected.GetComponent<cakeslice.Outline>());
            selected = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) includes the `Transform` of the `selected` itself and also nested children!

> Returns all components of Type type in the GameObject or any of its children.
>
> The search for components is carried out recursively on child objects, so it includes children of children, and so on.

also note that it has an optional parameter `bool` whether to include currently inactive or disabled components.

---

However why are you getting `Transform` and than `GetComponent<cakeslice.Outline>()>`? To destroy all `cakeslice.Outline>()` instances simply do

```
var outlines = selected.GetComponentsInChildren<cakeslice.Outline>(true);
foreach(var line in outline)
{
    Destroy(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I didnt realize it had to be used like that. We're working just fine now.